# Excel Data Model Relationships Pulling Entire Tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, datamodel

Going a bit crazy over this issue. I have a Data Model with several tables, each of which has a key field designed to connect it to the others. For example, "age_product" concats an age field and a string field for a product name. In my primary table, these will appear multiple times because the same product/age will appear in multiple states, etc. but in another "product" table, these are unique. Only one entry for each product/age combination, and a price that I need to pull.

I connect these two tables by the age_product key. Then I create a pivot table and add age and product as rows. Good so far. I add fields from the primary table. Good so far. I add the average price from the product table, and its identical in every age.

Out of curiosity, I filter to just one product, one age, then double click the pivot table to get the values that are getting pulled into this calculation. It shows that for Age 0 and Product X, every single entry from the product table has been pulled in. Its very clearly showing my age_product key and showing every age, every product, connecting them all to Age 0 Product X despite the key field not matching for those.

This happens identically for every age/product combo. Thank you so much for any insight you can provide, I don't know what to do. There's a unique age/product key but the Data Model is taking Age 0/Product X and matching it to every single combination despite mismatched keys.

Answer (score 2):

Bi-directional relationships are not possible in Power Pivot. As such, filtering via relationships only ever propagates from the one to the many side, not vice versa. Hence, in your case fields from the product table are capable of filtering the primary table, though fields from the primary table are not capable of filtering the product table.

One solution would be to create single-column 'bridge' tables for each of the fields from the primary table which you wish to use in your report, and create relationships between these bridge tables and your two current tables. Since the fields from these bridge tables could not by definition be on the many side of their relationship with the other two tables, they would be capable of filtering said tables.

Comment: Thanks, Jos. I tried this by making a bridge table that was just one column, the unique age_product key. I received the same results. Would I also have to add the product and the age to this bridge table, then use those as the source of my rows in a pivot table?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. For **each** of the fields from the Primary table which you wish to include in your Pivot Table, you will need to create a separate bridge table which comprises a unique list of entries for that field.

Comment: I have a unique age bridge table and a unique product bridge table. The Primary links to these two tables, and they each link to the secondary table which has the same. Then a pivot table with and Age 0 Product X row still pulls every single age and product from the secondary table.

Comment: And your Pivot Table now does not include any fields from the Primary table, correct?

Comment: So whenever I want to add a field that exists in both tables to my pivot, I have to explicitly select that field from the bridge table?

Comment: Not necessarily. In fact, it may even be on the contrary: if the only fields which you wish to include in your Pivot Table are common to both the primary and product table, then no bridge tables are necessary; you simply choose that from the product table when adding to the Pivot. It's only when you have a field which you wish to include within the Pivot that only exists within the primary table that you have to create the bridge table.